# Android - How to fire an event when any URL is clicked in any browser

Tags: java, android, background

I want to create a background service which reads every URL the user is visiting (before they visit).

I know you can use intent-filters defined in the manifest but the URl to be fired on has to be done before hand, I need it to read off a large database.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "I know you can use intent-filters defined in the manifest" -- not really. That only works when an app specifically wants to allow other apps to potentially handle the URL. Apps are welcome to load Web content themselves, without necessarily involving other apps.

Comment: I need to be able to intercept the url though when they are using a seperate browser, say the way malware bytes blocks specific websites because theyre dangerous,